# How to load files (File API HTML5) by creation date

Tags: javascript, html

I need to load some files (images) and list them by **creation date**.

I got an example of the File API HTML5, but the only attribute I can get using the File API is the *lastModifiedDate*.

Comment: Creation date is not exposed by the File APIs. All you get are size, type, lastModifiedDated, and name: http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#dfn-file.