# Getting File Creation Date and Author in Javascript or HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a web interface that allows user to select files using HTML% File API, and then I need to extract various file properties. I found a way of getting file name, last modified date, file size, file type using HTML5 File API, but am unable to figure out how to get file attributes like creation date and creator name.

Any pointers in this direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295577/how-to-load-files-file-api-html5-by-creation-date

Comment: is it possible to get it otherwise? without using FILE API?

Comment: `ActiveXObject`s on Windows. That's not recommended unless you are on a known secure intranet and they only work in IE.